# I got many dtypes errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataframe:

```
   *Ca *O *Ca  Ca  Hy
0    1   2   3   4   5
1    1             
2    1    5            
3    1    6  7   8            
4    5                
5    6         
6    6                
7    6                
8    9              
9    9  12          
10   9  9   10   11
```

and when I tried to contact it like this:
 `pd.concat([df] + [df+i for i in range(10, 250, 10)], ignore_index=True)` I get errors like `np.int is not iterable` and `can not concate str to int`

Also my dataframe contains `NAN` , and I use `df.fillna('', inplace=True)`  to replace NAN with nothing `''` which it seems problem to convert to an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `df.fillna(0,inplace=True)`,

It should give out desired output, asreplacing the NaN value would not affect you sum.

> Also my dataframe contains NAN , and I use `df.fillna('', inplace=True)`  to replace NAN with nothing `''` which it seems problem to convert to an int

As the data type of `''` is string (it is an empty string not nothing)

Comment: It should be an empty cell NOT  zero